# Null reference exception on PriorityQueue.RemoveItem

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, nullreferenceexception

A single instance of this error occurred, and I haven't been able to reproduce it, and unfortunately the logs don't offer any helpful information. The last operation on this thread seemed to finish fine, and then this unhandled exception pops up:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at System.Windows.Threading.PriorityQueue`1.RemoveItem(PriorityItem`1 item)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

I tried internet searching the `PriorityQueue.RemoveItem(item)` call in the stack trace, but I couldn't find anyone having a similar issue. There is nothing in the application event long to hint at a memory leak or anything else funky. Anyway, I was curious if anyone has seen something similar, or has any educated guess as to what could cause this.

Also, here's the code for the `PriorityQueue.RemoveItem(item)` method (Code for PriorityQueue class can be found [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/MS/Internal/PriorityQueue.cs)):

```
public void RemoveItem(PriorityItem<T> item)
{
    PriorityChain<T> chain = item.Chain;

    // Step 1: Remove the item from its priority chain.
    RemoveItemFromPriorityChain(item);

    // Step 2: Remove the item from the sequential chain.
    RemoveItemFromSequentialChain(item);

    // Note: we do not clean up empty chains on purpose to reduce churn.
}
```

I suppose the null reference exception is happening because `item` is null? Anyway, any ideas or guesses would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you test that item is not null before calling RemoveItem?  If not, I would add that check and log the condition to help narrow down why this is happening should it recur.

Comment: You do know that `Debug.Assert` is compiled to no-op in retail build, don't you? (Assuming you are using retail built based on lack of line numbers in call stack)

Comment: The `RemoveItem` call is part of .net, I added a link to the full code. So I have no control of that. Yes, I realize the `Debug.Assert` are ignored in my case, because I'm using release. I'll remove them from the example to eliminate confusion.